# can't get object from node js server

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api, get

I tried to make a get response for a specific id.
Instead of that, I get undefind on the console ...

For example, If I'll surf to => http://localhost:3005/api/books/1 I need to see the details of book 1:
{ id: 1, author: "Or", price: 250 }

Can I get some help?

```js
const express = require("express");
const server = express();

const books = [
  { id: 1, author: "Or", price: 250 },
  { id: 240, author: "Shay", price: 100 },
  { id: 3, author: "Hila", price: 70 },
];

server.get("/api/books", (request, response) => {
  response.json(books);
});

server.get("/api/books/:id", (request, response) => {
  const id = +request.param.id;
  const oneBook = books.find((b) => b.id === id);
  console.log(oneBook);
  response.json(oneBook);
});

server.listen(3005, () => console.log("Listening on http://localhost:3005"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

`params`, not `param`

Comment: Working... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance my level of English is very bad, so I can’t explain where you were wrong, but here is the code that solves your problem

```
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const books = [
  { id: 1, author: "Or", price: 250 },
  { id: 240, author: "Shay", price: 100 },
  { id: 3, author: "Hila", price: 70 },
];

server.get("/api/books", (request, response) => {
  response.json(books);
});

server.get("/api/books/:id", (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params
  const oneBook = books.filter(
    item => item.id === (+id)
  )
  console.log(oneBook);
  response.json(oneBook);
});

server.listen(3005, () => console.log("Listening on http://localhost:3005"));
```